# How to delete a column from a MySQL big table

Tags: php, mysql, query-optimization

I have a 250GB 500M rows MySQL table and would like to delete one of its columns. 
The column is VARCHAR(255). I would like to perform this operation with as little as possible down-time. Thoughts:

1. Is there any configuration I can add that will help this operation?
2. Would it be better to iterate in php before on each row and delete the value inside it?
3. Would it require OPTIMIZE TABLE afterwards?
4. What would be a reasonable time estimation for such a procedure?

Comment: `2.Would it be better to iterate in php before on each row and delete the value inside it?` -- Definitely not, do it in mysql itself.

Comment: Add index first of all on column which will be used in criteria. And don't do it using php. php will load its variables in RAM, there's no RAM to handle 250 GB at the same time, so you should loop through chunks that will definitely take more time than mysql operation.

Comment: @DainisAbols But wouldn't it take ~ a day?

Comment: You can always try to clone the table. Redirect users to the new table and do the delete. After that redirect them back.

Comment: PHP could actually be used, but not at once (not for dropping column). This is a quite big MySQL operation and will take some time, by dropping column in sql the DB will become unavailable during the procedure while performing SET = null in PHP with delay would still leave the DB available for other simultaneous users. But, of course, if the column should simply be dropped, PHP should not be used.

Answer (score 0):

To assure minimal downtime I would personally backup and restore to an alternative database and then do the 'drop column' before restoring again.

1. [link](https://www.bitrixsoft.com/support/training/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=22&LESSON_ID=1274)
2. It might be, but it will take longer time and is more prone to errors I would say.
3. Yes, good idea, also, consider using ANALYZE TABLE before hand

OPTIMIZE TABLE;
The OPTIMIZE command should be run when the DBMS is offline for scheduled maintenance. The command is nonstandard SQL.